# C++ HTTP always 301 using sockets

Tags: c++, http, sockets, http-status-code-301

I'm sick of this. ALWAYS when I make a HTTP GET query from a C/C++ program using just plain sockets I get 301 Moved Permanently's. Normally I'd use libcURL, but in this case I don't want to add another library, I just need to download one flat identification file from one fixed server.

This is my current query:

```
GET /game/getversion.jsp?user=nightcracker&password=yeahright&version=12 HTTP/1.1\r\n
Connection: close\r\n
Host: www.minecraft.net\r\n
Accept-Encoding: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2\r\n
\r\n
```

I have tried EVERYTHING, and everything just gets answered with this funny message:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/0.6.32
Date: Tue, 15 Mar 2011 02:18:11 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 185
Connection: close
Location: http://www.minecraft.net/game/getversion.jsp?user=nightcracker&password=yeahright&version=12

<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/0.6.32</center>
</body>
</html>
```

I remember this issue from before and I ragequitted before. Now I want to fix this damn bugger. So tell me SO, why do all my HTTP queries always give back a 301?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, besides the issue with the Accept-Encoding, the query was fine. The problem was that I resolved in my socket code to "minecraft.net" instead of "www.minecraft.net". RAAAAH. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see anything obviously wrong since the redirected URI appears to be the same as the original GET request URI, so I would suggest downloading the command-line curl and running that in verbose mode against the same target. Perhaps it will show something in its output that can point you in the right direction. There's a chance that this is a badly-configured server or badly written JSP, so keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the problem you have on the Minecraft server (I don't have an account) but

```
Accept-Encoding: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2\r\n
```

what the heck is that?  Header fields that might go in requests include

- `Accept:` MIME types (e.g. what you have there)
- `Accept-Charset:` charsets (e.g. `utf-8`)
- `Accept-Encoding:` encodings (e.g. `gzip`)
- `Accept-Language:` languages (e.g. `en`)

and you seem to be mixing them up.

Comment: Changing Accept-Encoding to Accept fixes nothing, though it was incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the server is redirecting the client to another location. You just have to issue another 
request to the URL coming back in the "Location" header of the 3xx respone

OOPs realized that the redirect location is the same as the original URI. DOes this URL work from the browser? If so you might try adding a User-Agent header in the request that contains the same User-Agent that the browser is sending.

Answer (score 0):

You can either specify the correct URL ([www.minecraft.net](http://www.minecraft.net)) or tell libcurl to follow redirects automatically:

```cpp
curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
```